# Richfaces and Headless mode

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am working on richfaces and everything seem to work on my dev machine (windows os). Deploying it on a linux machine,I don't see any images that comes with richfaces components(like sorting images) and throws this exception.

```
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'tnsd03748:1.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$000(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:53)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:142)
```

which can happen only when the code tries to deal with GUI on a linux/unix environment which is headless. Maybe the issue will be resolved when i add `-Djava.awt.headless=true`.I just want to know has anyone come across such an issue with richfaces and is there any configuration to get it right.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using richfaces on CentOS, and I haven't had this problem. I can't check now, but I guess the tomcat has been installed by default to use `headless=true`, so give it a try.